# Need help to develop a C# code to put the header validation

Tags: c#

I have a flat file with comma separated values which need to be transfer to a datatable and the values on the first line is header name, will be used as columns name of the datatable. But Before that, I need to check if all required header (Some Mandatory headers) are available in the flat file. Please help me to develop a C# code to put the header validation.

```
`.
 .
 .
 /getting full file path of Uploaded file and read all text            
 System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@path);
 string line;
 while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)            
 {
  string[] linetemp = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
  if(tblcsv.Rows.Count==0)
 {
  foreach (string ColName in linetemp)
  {
   tblcsv.Columns.Add(ColName); //Creating columns with available headers names
  }
  }                
  tblcsv.Rows.Add();
  .
  .
  .
  `//remaining code
```

For example
If the flat file will contain
datetime,status,Assignee,Reporter,Duration,Col1,Col2,Remarks
1504451523568,Inprogress,ABC,BCD,120,True,B,comments...
1504451523567,Completed,DFG,BCD,120,True,B,comments...
1504451523566,unassigned,VNB,BCD,160,,B,comments...
1504451523565,Inprogress,ERT,FGH,150,True,,comments...
 and I need to check that only First line have all mandaory header(like- datetime,Status,Assignee and Duration).

Comment: we dont write code for you - we will help you with specific issues..

Comment: How would you do it by hand? You get a list of mandatory headers, take the first one, then go through all the headers to see if any of them matches the mandatory one. If yes, great, take the second one of the mandatory headers and repeat. If not, then that mandatory header is missing, so the whole thing is invalid. Only of you find a match for all mandatory headers it's valid. -- you already have a place in your code to handle the headers (`if(tblcsv.Rows.Count==0)`), so somewhere in there you should put that validation.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Corak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tired to implement your particular requirement with a sample Csv file from online. Csv file can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SVU13_7.2.1/com.ibm.ismsaas.doc/import/r_sample_csv_files.html),  I may not have a sophisticated code, but tried to take a simplest way to solve this particular problem.

Below is the short version of code which is of your importance.

```
String firstLine;
var fileStream = new FileStream( @ "C:\Users\user\Desktop\AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv", FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read);
 using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8)) {
firstLine = streamReader.ReadLine();
}
var values = firstLine.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++) {
values[i] = values[i].Trim();

}
if (values.Length == 4)
                {
                    int count=0;
                    IList<string> newList = new List<string> { "MXASSETInterface", "SRM_SaaS_ES", "EN", "AddChange" };
                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                    {

                        if (newList.Contains(values[i]))
                        {
                            count++;
                            newList.Remove(values[i]);
                        }

                    }

                    if (count == 4)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("head is correct");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("head is incorrect");

                    }

                }
```

The complete console application can be found with below code, which can be run direct

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            String firstLine;
            var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv", FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read);
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                firstLine = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }
            if (firstLine != null)
            {
                var values = firstLine.Split(',');
                Console.WriteLine(firstLine);
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = values[i].Trim();
                    Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
                }
                if (values.Length == 4)
                {
                     int count=0;
                    IList<string> newList = new List<string> { "MXASSETInterface", "SRM_SaaS_ES", "EN", "AddChange" };
                    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                    {

                        if (newList.Contains(values[i]))
                        {
                            count++;
                            newList.Remove(values[i]);
                        }

                    }

                    if (count == 4)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("head is correct");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("head is incorrect");

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("header is Invalid");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("header is Invalid");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please check if file is available or path is correct", e.Message);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: appreciate your help. but in my case position of the header values may vary.

Comment: @SubrataSarkar I updated the code with position unknown. But I guess you are beforehand sure the count of header and what should be the header value. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using CsvHelpet library for parsing the CSV file. It allows to define a class that represents a row in your file. Header names are property names by default or they can be mapped usimg fluent API.

var csv = new CsvReader( textReader ); var records = csv.GetRecords();

Get records will fail if some headers are missing.